# How can i implement page views counting using ajax call?

Tags: javascript, analytics, visitors

Supposing I have number of different resources on my site and I want count page views each of them. Of course, I can just increment on each request, but 1)I want only unique views 2)I don't want cheating.

So, idea which came to my mind is to approve page view with ajax call. And not simple one, but tricky. User should make some work client-side and i should check results of that work server-side and increment views only if user did it right. I think it should be some encryption function with "backdoor" for quick server checking. But i have near zero experience with this cryptostuff and don't know if such things even exist.

Thx for attention.
p.s. Feel free to tell me if i should go to jail, mad house or 6th grade.

Comment: I think you're overestimating amount of malicious users. If this system is only counting page views and users don't get any benefit from it, they have no incentive to fool the system.

Comment: Actually, it's not "just" page views. And users have benefit from it. Situation is similar to Youtube.

Answer (score 0):

I would not bother about all this client-side work stuff. The client code is in user's hands, user knows how it works and can replay the code to perform the work.

I'd suggest just putting some restrictions on the user's environent. Like not allowing two votes (page view or whatever) from the same IP. This is simple to implement and is widely used. Of course, malicious users will want to vote via proxies, but then you can limit a number of distinct IPs for a user, such that if user behaves well, he won't exceed it.

Comment: It is overkill to introduce some "User" entity with accompanying things only for views counting, isn't it? And it will be just difficult to explain the benefits of registration.

Comment: How do users get benefit from that system again? And how did you plan to identify unique users?

Comment: Lets assume we're talking about Youtube and it's video "benefits" from popularity. I planned identify unique users by IP(probably, I didn't get your question).

Comment: Well, don't mind the last part then. Treat every IP as unique users and you'll be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the algorithm is HashCash([official site](http://hashcash.org)). It has practical limitations of usage due to large difference between processing power of mobile computers and static ones. So, one should read about "Memory Bound Puzzles"([link](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~sdoshi/index_files/fulltext.pdf)) because of little difference of memory access speed on different devices.